# Multithreading - In an array what should I protect?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

I'm working on some code that has a global array that can be accessed by two threads for reading writing purposes.

There will be no batch processing where a range of indexes are read or written, so I'm trying to figure out if I should lock the entire array or only the array index I am currently using.

The easiest solution would be to consider the array a CS and put a big fat lock around it, but can I avoid this and just lock an index?

Cheers.

Comment: You can. If that's not quite the answer you were expecting, improving the question should result in improved answers.

Comment: You have to make your own decision as to what is a "logical" grouping of data to lock (and then figure out how to have a lock on a per-group basis).

Comment: I think you need to profile with a realistic running scenario to decide at which level of granularity you lock.

Comment: If the array size doesn't change, and you're using a C like array `arr[x] = v` then read and write operations are atomic - why do you need to protect the access?

Comment: @ring0 - that will depend on what is on the array. something as simple as a 64bit variable on a 32 bit system and t wont be atomic anymore

Comment: I was assuming basic types. In the case of more complex types, a semaphore per 100 indexes: `lock sem[index/100]`... would reduce the memory usage.

Comment: Just to be clear, are both threads writing and reading, or is there only one writer?

Comment: @juanchopanza both can read and write the data

Answer (score 4):

Locking one index implies that you can keep track of which thread is accessing what part of the array. Keeping track of this information, which is shared between the reading and the writing thread, implies that you have one lock around this information. So, you still end up with a global lock.
In this situation, I think that the most efficient approaches are:
- using a reader/writer lock
- or dividing the big array into a few subsets, each subset using a distinct lock.

Comment: @Candag: Of course not! One thread just needs to know the simple method that determines which lock is associated with the aimed subset of the array.

Comment: @Candag: see ring0's comment to the question for a simple possibility to map a semaphore or mutex to a ranges of 100 array elements.  If your threads tend to work on array elements that are in close proximity, you could do something like `mutex_arr[idx%16]` to map each mutex to every 16th array item.

Answer (score 1):

If this is C++ i suggest you to use STL containers. `std::vector` or something else which suits your job. They are fast, easy to use, no memory leaks.

If you want to do it all by your self, then of course one method will be to use a single mutex ( which is bad ).
or you can use some [reader writer thingy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem) for the whole array.

I think its not feasible to make each element of an array thread safe with its own lock!! that would eat your memory. Check the link and there are 3 solutions with different out comes. Test them out and use the best for your case. ( don't think like "ok i think my program needs the readers preference algorithm". try using it in your system and decide. because we really cant assume such things *sometimes* )

Comment: Standard library containers, specifically `std::vector<>` mentioned, are **not** thread-safe for anything but exclusive-reads. In that they are no different than a `Type ar[N]` block. As soon as a writer is introduced you *must* bring protection of some kind (mutexes, etc).

Comment: Even if it's a vector I can't write and read on the same index. With vectors we have other issues though (http://shortbytes.blogspot.pt/2012/08/whats-wrong-with-vectors.html)

Comment: I think you should clarify what you mean by *thread safe* here, because OP might get the impression that somehow `std::vector` is safe under writing threads, which is not the case at all. As soon as one of the threads is writing, thread safety goes out of the window.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Ya good point. I edited and removed that part.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of knowing what will be optimal unless you profile under realistic running conditions. I would suggest implementing an array-like class, where you can lock a varying number of elements in groups. Then you fine-tune the size of these groups.

Another option would be to enqueue all read/write operations using an [active object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object). This would make all access sequential, and means you could use a non-concurrent array type to store the data. It would require some sort of concurrent queue data structure under the hood.