# Multithreading - Raytracer

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, variables, optimization

I've finished my raytracer now but im trying to learn threads to optimize the render time. To represent each pixels of my window im using a int8_t * (4 int8_t / pixel for R/G/B/A). Here is a sample of what im trying to do :

Number of threads set : 4

[0]-------[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEAPh.png)[2]-------[3][4]-------[5][6]-------[7]
[Thread 1][Thread 2][Thread 3][Thread 4]

For an array of 8, each thread take 2 cells but i want them to work simultaneously on the array. Is this possible if each thread work on a specific part ?

On this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEAPh.png) (ptr * is the int8_t *) you can see each thread have an area of effect on the array (start position to end position for the actual array part).

Is this possible if each thread work on a specific part ?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I would suggest maybe taking a look at some other questions on SO involving managing multi-thread access to arrays, such as these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925294
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315200

Comment: i've readed it but those don't really resolve my problem, thanks for you help btw

Comment: I'm curious - why are you using `int8_t` (and not `uint8_t`)? It's rare for "negative amount of red, green, or blue" to make any sense.

Comment: Good suggestion , error from me , thanks !

Comment: in general, threading is only really helpful if there are delays in the program, where some other 'thread' could still be doing useful work.  Manipulating an array (usually) does not involve delays, so multithreading will slow down the program due to context switching, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to have a multithreaded ray tracer with all the threads writing to the same output buffer without extra synchronization, **if**:

1. The output array isn't moving around.
2. The parts of the array being written by the threads don't overlap.
3. On some platforms, you might also have to make sure that threads never attempt an unaligned write, which suggests that it's not a great idea to have one thread writing the red channel while another writes the green channel of the same pixel.

For best performance, you probably don't want two threads trying to write to the same cache line at the same time.  Rather than having the threads play leapfrog through the array, consider carving up the image into larger contiguous chunks.

I usually set each thread going on its own row in the image.  When one finishes a row, I have it work on the next unassigned row.  Doling out the portions this way does require some synchronization, but that's very minor and generally won't be under heavy contention.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i'll try to finish it then !

Comment: As a newbie on optimisation :     
Why would two threads writing on the same cache line be bad, I am familiar with cache misses and don't see the problem.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but my understanding is that if two cores are trying to read and write to the same cache line, there can be delays as the hardware ensures that both cores get a consistent view of the cache line.